# CFUUID generating new UUID every time I run the app

Tags: objective-c, keychain

I am trying to use alternative to UUID deprecated method to store my unique key in keychain so that I can use this for accessing my online database.

I am doing this :

```
            CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
            CFStringRef generatedUUIDString = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
            CFRelease(uuid);
            NSString* hashKey = [(NSString*)generatedUUIDString autorelease];

            KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"MyGAME" accessGroup:nil];
            [keychainItem setObject:hashKey forKey:(id)kSecValueData];

            NSLog(@"%@", [keychainItem objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData]);

            [keychainItem release];
```

But when I am retrieving my key from the keychain it returns me new value each time.  I am using KeychainItemWrapper. Shouldn't hashkey be the same everytime I call the method below? what I am doing wrong here?.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to save it to your `NSUserDefaults`

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:UUID forKey:@"UUID"];
```

And check if it already exists everytime your app starts.

```
if([defaults objectForKey:@"UUID"]){...}
```

Comment: I thought the whole point of avoiding NSUSerDefaults is to keep that unique UDID consistent even after app is deleted and reinstalled. Am I wrong?

Comment: As you have seen, the UUID changes everytime (hence why you save it).  It is still unique per app, but it loses some of it's value if it changes. If you want another solution try [this](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5) library by Georg Kitz.